# Changing the Binding Order of network interfaces does not affect routing decesions

Tags: networking, routing

I have a computer with two network interfaces. The main one, which leads to our main network, and a secondary one, which leads to its own little network. When both are enabled, the traffic intended for the main network wanders off into the secondary card and is lost. I tried changing the binding order on the interfaces, but this did not help.

[image: Changing the binding order]

Answer (score 1):

Windows decides what network interface to use based on the metric, changing the binding order does not change the metric. You can the metric on the interfaces manually by opening up  Network Interfaces from the Control Panel and then Choosing Properties → Ipv4 → Advanced... → Uncheck Automatic Metric and set your own value. Remember that the default metric is 10 and that lower numbers have a higher priority.

[image: Order]